# How to get snakemake to --use-conda by default?

Tags: conda, snakemake

My Snakefiles contain "conda" directives, and I always invoke snakemake with the `--use-conda` flag.

Is there a way to have this flag enabled by default? That is, can I get snakemake to use conda by default without explicitly adding `--use-conda` to every invocation?

Comment: Good point.  Many of my Snakefiles do not even run without Conda or Mamba. Having to add `--use-conda` and `--conda-frontend mamba` to every invocation of `snakemake` is tedious. Moreover, other users need to be instructed to add these flags. It make re-reproducibility harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define an alias for snakemake as

```
alias snakemake='snakemake --use-conda'
```

but then if you don't want to set `--use-conda` you would have either to remove the alias (`unalias snakemake`) or use a different name for the alias (e.g. `alias mysnakemake='snakemake --use-conda'`).

But really, I would just write `--use-conda` throughout to avoid confusion.

**UPDATE**

*UPDATE 2: This below doesn't work anymore in (at least) 7.32.4*

After @OronNavon comments, maybe something like this could do. On top of your Snakefile add:

```
if 'use_conda' in config and config['use_conda']:
    workflow.use_conda = True
```

where `use_conda` is a boolean variable that you read from a configuration file. It should work, but again, in my opinion it makes things confusing...

Comment: thanks, I should have clarified - I'm hoping for a configuration file or something similar, which would ideally be included in the project folder in the Snakefile or alongside it.  A global configuration file would also work, but I haven't found anything similar in the docs.

Comment: aha! I didn't know it's possible to set `workflow.use_conda = True` within the Snakefile, that's good enough for me - I'll just add that statement and avoid any config file or global alias altogether. Thanks @dariober!

Comment: Setting `workflow.use_conda = True` does not work anymore?  `can't set attribute 'use_conda'`. I am using snakemake 7.32.4

Comment: @sjdh: I can confirm it doesn't work anymore - it was a hackish solution from the start...

Comment: Thanks @dariober. I have settled for an alias. Users of my project need to read the documentation and remember to add `---use-conda` for most targets.

Answer (score 1):

One way to have a "global" configuration file is to create a snakemake profile, then change your alias to always load it.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/snakemake/my_profile
echo "use-conda: True" >> ~/.config/snakemake/my_profile/config.yaml
```

Then set an alias:

```
alias snakemake='snakemake --profile my_profile'
```